# Downloading prebuilt Cronet (Chromium network stack) library

Tags: shared-libraries, chromium, cronet

Is there any way to download `Cronet` prebuilt library?

I'd like to use `cronet.<version>.so` (dynamic/shared library) on Desktop for debugging purposes. Is there any way to download it directly rather than building it from the source?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/net-dev/c/RdMsMNLwSDw/m/VmGvFMI8AgAJ), chromium net-dev team does not provide prebuild version of cronet anymore.

Comment: This might be useful though -> https://github.com/Sunbreak/cronet.dart

Answer (score 0):

Cronet and its bindings are available as a regularly updated Maven dependency: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=cronet#org.chromium.net.